# WTforms SelectField disabled option

Tags: jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms, disable

I am trying to add SelectField in my Flask app and I want first option to be disabled, but can't manage to do it !
This is my HTML code:

```
      <div class="w3-col m6 w3-center">
            <h3>{{ form.manager.label }}</h3>
            {{ form.manager(class="w3-select w3-border w3-round-large") }}
              {% for option in form.manager %}
                  {% if loop.first %}
                      {{ option(disabled="") }}
                  {% else %}
                      {{ option }}
                  {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

What I get with this is - my choices printed under my SelectField input!

How can I fix this?